# Dynamically generate a Drupal page for each row in a table

Tags: drupal

Is there a way in Drupal 8 to dynamically generate a page for each row in a table in a database?

If I have a database named School, with a table Students, with these columns and rows:

```
ID |FirstName   |LastName   |Email                  |User       |HiddenField
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |Adam       |Johnson    |ajohnson@example.com   |ajohn1     |Blah
 2  |Bob        |Smith      |bsmith@example.com     |bsmith0    |Foo
```

Is there a module or setting to create simple pages with these URLs with content like this:

http://mywebpage.com/students/1

```
First name: Adam
Last name: Johnson
Email address: ajohnson@example.com
Username: ajohn1
```

http://mywebpage.com/students/2

```
First name: Bob
Last name: Smith
Email address: bsmith@example.com
Username: bsmith0
```

Note that there is a HiddenField that isn't displayed, so this solution should include the ability to exclude certain columns.

I've tried using the Views module to create a new page type, but I don't see in there where to specify a table or anything like that.

Comment: You don't mention which version of drupal. Ofcourse you can just read the DB and generate pages, but if you truely want your data integrated with drupal, you probably want to import your data as a drupal node or entity.

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback. I've updated the question with the version number.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data to an associative array with the keys named as the fields, you can write the following:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('students')
  ->fields('students', [
    'id',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'email',
    'user'
  ]);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc();
```

After that, you can iterate through `$results` and create the pages:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  // Create node object.
  $node = Node::create([
    'type' => 'page',
    'title' => 'whatever you want',
    'field_machine_name' => 'field_value',
    'firstname' => $result['firstname'],
  ]);
  $node->save();
}
```

Please keep in mind to use dependency injection wherever you can. Also you can check for errors like is there a bundle called 'page', and run it only if there is.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but do I put this in a php file, and does it matter where in the folder structure I put it, or is a custom module I have to make, or something else?

Comment: What's the use case? Do you want to push a button and when it is submitted import the data from database to pages? Do you want it to do automatically when a new row is inserted to the database? Do you want to run it when CRON runs? Also, as @2pha mentioned, it is better to already import the data as entities.

Comment: Good questions. I want it done automatically when a new row is inserted. I'll look into importing the data as entities. Should I start with this? https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-11-06/the-best-way-to-import-content-to-drupal-8

Comment: Actually, if it's a new site you could do the migration with migrate_dc module, which is a new module allowing users to migrate default content through site installation. If it's an already existing site, you could either import the basic content manually, and do it each time when another row is inserted, or subscribe to an event when something is inserting the new row to the table.